# Generate Random file Name on S3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i'm new to Amazon S3 Bucket (noob) and i'm trying to figure out a way to generate a random file name when i upload it to the bucket. I can write few lines to make this happen before uploading but it is not the idea. is there a way to do it directly when uploading on the aws s3 interface?.
I want to set my uploaded file

`my_file_name.jpg` to 
`240_F_76350438_VB68wi4VlsYjk0kX6PGbYJbEIYsVJ4Qf.jpg` 
for example. Thank you.

Comment: what method you will be using for upload i.e aws cli, boto3 etc ?

Comment: Most programming languages have the ability to generate a random UUID string, which should do the job.

Comment: I know i can generate a random UUID via any programming language. The question is if is there any s3 bucket setup or configuration to do this automatically on upload? just using the s3 gui.